# What's kind of event happend on target control when I use errorProvider.SetIconAlignment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Does anybody know what's kind of event happend on target control when I use `errorProvider.SetIconAlignment()` method?

for example:

When I call `errorProvider.SetIconAlignment(mytextbox1, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleRight);`

on mytextbox1 I want to catch this event whenever SetIconAlignment was called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an event that ErrorProvider could be using. In fact, I can't find any event at all that's related to this.

Based on what I've used from ErrorProvider, there is no other way than to extend the method, like this:

```
// Defines an extended version of the ErrorProvider
public class ExtendedErrorProvider : ErrorProvider, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // That will replace the SetIconAlignment from the base class when you call it from outside the class
    public void SetIconAlignment(Control control, ErrorIconAlignment value)
    {
        // Will raise an event just before changing the property
        OnPropertyChanging("IconAlignment");
        // Changed the property using the base class
        base.SetIconAlignment(control, value);
        // Will raise an event just after the property has changed
        OnPropertyChanged("IconAlignment");
    }

    // This will ensure that whenever you bind methods to be called on the PropertyChanging, they will get called for the specific property...
    protected void OnPropertyChanging(string property) { if (PropertyChanging != null) PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(property)); }
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    // This will ensure that whenever you bind methods to be called on the PropertyChanged, they will get called for the specific property...
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property) { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Now, outside this class, you can do something like this:

```
errorProvider1.PropertyChanging += WhatNeedsToBeDoneBeforeChanging(...);
errorProvider1.PropertyChanged += WhatNeedsToBeDoneAfterChanging(...);
```

Comment: Events are good ...I was thinking more along the lines of observer/observable ...but good answer.

Comment: Build your own extended class based on ErrorProvider is the good idea. But it's seem there's no way to catch up event when error icon was set to mytextbox1?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Check out [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PropertyNotifyPart1.aspx) from The Code Project. There they are using a custom implementation of IPropertyNotification to pass other parameters along with the property name (like old and new value or, on your scenario, the object/control itself).